# How can I recreate this snooker shot where the ball stops instantly after striking a cushion?

Tags: technique, snooker, cue-sports

In [this match](https://youtu.be/q-91ZCBVUes?t=41) between Willie Thorne and Jimmy White, Jimmy pots the pink ball (at 0:41) and the cue ball stops extremely suddenly in perfect position to finish on the black.

[image]

Whilst playing pool I have done this shot a few times without conscious effort and I'm wondering how it is done. I imagine it requires a huge amount of spin and a good follow through to achieve, but is this a shot that can be done consistently given the right technique or does it rely mostly on luck to achieve?

Comment: Considering pool is generally a more popular sport, I have added the pool tag as well to bring more attention to this question.

Comment: Please don't do that; if you want to bring more attention to a question, you can [add a bounty to it](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) (although there is a delay before you can do this, I think 2 days).

Comment: I completely disagree. This shot can be achieved either in pool or snooker using the same principles. There may be small differences between the cue, balls and table but these aren’t that significant.

Comment: @Ambo100 Please do not revert edits made by a mod.  You're welcome to discuss in [chat] if you wish, but it's not appropriate to undo edits like this.  As for pool vs snooker; please remember that we're a site for discussing *competitive sports*, and while pool and snooker are both, it is correct to use the single appropriate tag, not both, when asking a question relating to one sport or the other.

Comment: I've created a [cue-sports tag](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cue-sports) for questions like this which could apply across the various similar games.

Comment: I believe it is appropriate to revert a tag edit when it is appropriate to do so. If my question is about a snooker shot that I wish to recreate in pool, is it not appropriate to use this tag? Feel free to cover these comments to chat.